# Geometry objects disappear

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]

In version 3.0 have Christmas lights connected to the leaves of my tree with geometry nodes. In the modifier it says "no group output attributes connected." When I apply the geometry node, my lights disappear. How do I fix this? I would also like to know how I add a second group of objects to the tree to add ornaments, with geometry nodes. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/VynJrxedBuQ

Answer (score 3):

One option is to make the instances real by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Make instances real*.
You need to have your main object (the one that contains the geometry nodes) selected and the mouse needs to be over the viewport.

[image]

Edit 1: The "Make instances real" works, but not as in 2.93, so my answer is not 100% correct.

Instead of making the instances like in geometry nodes, now makes instances per vertex.

It's already reported as a bug, but I'm not sure if this is the new intended way to work

Edit 2: According to a repost from a developer (bug report) it's already tracking the way this works (because of the primitives inside GEo-Nodes) but for now, the trick is to click on the checkbox *As Instance* inside the *Object Info* node, Before you try to make it real (tried and works).
[image]

Comment: I just edited my answer and added an animated gif

Comment: @JustMe I added another edit at the end to make it work correctly

Comment: Can you edit your question and add all the steps and issues with some screenshots so it's easier to see

Comment: Edit your question to add more info and images instead of adding a lot of comments, it's better, specially if someone else wants to add a new answer based on your descriptions. the only way to add an image here is with a hyperlink like imgur

Comment: You just need to select your mesh, put the mouse on top your mesh and press CTRL + A, a menu will show up and at the bottom, you will see "Make instances Real" (As i explained). Make this exercise: Open a new Blend File, add a Sphere, select the Sphere, put the mouse on top of the sphere and press CTRL + A > "Make instances Real". I can't really explain it simplier than that, and i will really tell you with all the respect, that you are not reading what we put, so we could be able to help you. EDIT YOUR MAIN QUESTION WITH MORE INFO AND MORE IMAGES, INSTEAD OF ADDING MORE COMMENTS.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using collections, (but this probably holds if you are just using simple object for your instance).
I had this problem and I realized that I had moved my collection that I was using as the instances so the Collection info node did not know where the asset was.
[image]

So just go into you Collection Info node and choose your assets again. (Or dump the Collection Info node ) and drag in your assets (the instance you want painted over your mesh) and hook it up to the instance on points node.

(Haven't posted here before not sure if the image I have supplied will appear correctly)