# Want to cloth-sim a geo-node instanced object with Pinned vertex group

Tags: cloth-simulation, geometry-nodes

I am using instances of a petal object to create a flower with Geometry Nodes and I have defined a pin Vertex Group that I want to somehow specify in a cloth simulation:

[image]

In Geometry nodes, I'm thinking I have to Realize Instances so that each petal will be cloth-simulated independently:

[image]

However, whether or not I Realize Instances in GN, I am unable to specify a Pin vertex group for the cloth-sim:

[image]

I've tried to Apply the GN modifier and the object [disappears](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250203/111042), I've tried Make Instances Real and [things go really crazy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245144/111042) with many duplicates of the GN object.

Here's a link to an [example blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6ym8p4fuale5og/flower_GN.blend?dl=0).

Comment: maybe i am too dumb, but i can't find any vertex group in your example file for [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uAGH.png and no pin entry....

Comment: @Chris as I understand it, the *flower_petal* has a pin group as shown in screenshot 1. It's the prototype for the GN instances of the flower. The problem is that the pin group is not added for the instance copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer the vertex group (*pin*) of the instance object (*flower_petal*) to the flower object with the *Geometry Nodes* modifier (*Flower_GN.001*) you need to do the following:

- create the *pin* group on the flower object (*Flower_GN.001*)
- add a new input slot (*Pin Group*) to the *Group Input* of the *flower GN* (in the node editor)
- add a *Capture Attribute* node between the *Object Info* (instance object) and the *Instance on Points* node
- wire the *Pin Group* input to the *Value* input slot of the *Capture Attribute* node
- put the *Realize Instance* node after the *Instance on Points* node. (It does not work after the *Join Geometry* node)
- in the *Geometry Modifier* settings select *pin* as value for the *Pin Group*
- select the *pin* group in the *Cloth* settings.
- check if the *pin* group on the *flower_petal* (instance object) is correct. Note that *pin* is not the same as *Pin* when you type the name.

The nodes in black frames have been changed/added.

[image: geometry node setup]

Vertex group and modifier settings:

[image: vertex group and modifier settings]

Please give the *pin* group a bit more weight otherwise all the petals hang down limply ;-)

**Note about Blender 3.1 RC** -
When you open the blend file in Blender 3.1 the *Realize Instances* node gives you a warning about **"Legacy Behaviour"**. In the *side panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Node > Properties* there is a checkbox. You need to uncheck it to make the transfer of the *pin* vertex group work.

Comment: Wow: service with a smile.   How it manged to get the Vertex Group vertices as Point Float Values, is a bit mystifying to me.   Thanks so very mucho!   On to adujstments and adding forces to make the simulation more interesting...