# Two particle systems interact (collide) with each other

Tags: particles, physics

Because I want to duplicate this rig many times, how do I make the spheres collide/deform/interact with the planes without making the instances real? (Making them real and then duplicating creates unworkable render times... way too many faces etc.)

Here two particles systems (Emitters), the sphere has collision, the plane collision and cloth physics, with a pin group so it doesn't fall.
[image]

I want to produce this without making Instances Real:
[image]

Is this possible, from the Blender manual I understand that particles need mesh data to interact with. I'd appreciate any help and I also appreciate this has likely been asked before but struggling to find an applicable precedent here, please link if you can. Sincere thanks.

Comment: Seems like it's not really possible. Sims need geometry to work, (ref. manual), so not possible without applying. Made several attempts at doing the same with Geometry nodes, I can get the spheres w collision but not the cloth. Instances don't seem to inherit physics, I have read here and elsewhere that sims aren't really possible yet in Geometry Nodes, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is getting close, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255641/want-to-cloth-sim-a-geo-node-instanced-object-with-pinned-vertex-group but it seems we can no longer set pin groups via Geometry Modifier since 3.5